# prettyPhoto script isn't working

Tags: javascript, css, gallery, prettyphoto

I had a previous question about working with a lightbox for this website www.chrissybulakites.com .. now I got the photos to load and fade properly into the gallery setting, however my script doesn't seem to be showing up when I placed it where the website told me to.

Can anyone help me out with this? I'm very much a beginner when it comes to this style, just a designer looking to help out a fellow friend.

Comment: what exactly is the problem?  you said that the images load and fade properly...

Comment: The arrows don't show up for the next photo to load or to close the fade.. not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong with the coding.

Comment: please post your code...

Comment: Notes 1)  Java != JavaScript 2) 
*"Thanks!

Rob"* == Noise

Comment: can you view the source on the website I linked? not enough characters to show ... http://www.chrissybulakites.com

Answer (score 0):

These three resources are not available at the specified [relative] paths:

```
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen" charset="utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

which are interpreted by the browser as

```
http://www.chrissybulakites.com/js/jquery.js
http://www.chrissybulakites.com/css/prettyPhoto.css
http://www.chrissybulakites.com/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js
```

Check to be sure that they're actually there -- the js/ and css/ directories should be at the same level as index.html (or whatever the default page is), and that the files have the correct permissions for the http server to serve them, etc.

I looked in Chrome's Javascript Console and saw that that those URLs were returning 404 Not Found -- Chrome and Firefox both have developer tools built-in that will alert you to these kinds of problems.